# Android app crashes opening InputStream from an XML

Tags: java, android, xml, url

I made a SAX parser that accepts an InputStream as file to parse. If I use a local file it works, but if I try to get it from the internet it crashes when it opens the Input Stream.

There is the code:

```
    URL url = new URL(http://www.myDomain.com/xml/device.xml);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();

    ...

parser.parse(inStream, handler);
```

I have been trying it in several ways I have seen in other questions and it always crashes at `InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();` or similar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the stacktrace you get?

Comment: Where can I find it? I started programming on Android yesterday and I amb a bit lost with the debugger view. Sorry.

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) on how to solve crashes.

Comment: More specifically to your question, this might be a [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?lq=1)

Comment: Looking at the Stacktrace I have seen the exception you say. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I saw in that post that I forgot the Internet permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be `NetworkOnMainThreadException` you should not run costly operations like Network Connection on Main thread

Call that method in the following way

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Call your network connection method 
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: I tried and it did not work, but after adding Internet permissions it did. Thanks!